# Getting error command does not exist in task scheduling Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-scheduler

I am following this tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-cronjobs-with-laravel/

but when I type in command line `php artisan make:list` i get an error message

```
  [ReflectionException]
  Class App\Console\Command\Test123 does not exist
```

How to fix above issue? What am I doing wrong?

## Test123.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Carbon\Carbon;

use Response;
use Config;
use DB;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class Test123 extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'abcd';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'some description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
           $parameters = [
        'attribute1' => 'val1',
        'attribute2' => 'val2',
        '_token' => Config::get('app.secret')
        ];
        $formattedParameters = http_build_query($parameters);
        $statusCode = 200;
        $url = "url?{$formattedParameters}"; 

        $client = new Client();
        $res = $client->get($url);

        $jsonArray = json_decode($res->getBody(),true);
        $field1= $jsonArray['field1'];

        DB::table('table_name')->insert(
    ['field1' => $field1]
);
    }
}
```

## Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Carbon\Carbon;

use Response;
use Config;
use DB;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;


class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Command\Test123::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {

        $schedule->command('abcd')->everyMinute();



    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: @apokryfos I did but does not seem to work either :/ I created a new file HappyBirthday as per the tutorial but then HappyBirthday does not exist too. if I remove App\Console\Command\Test123::class then I can execute other commands. But is there a way to flush everything from memory? clear cache or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues.

First, in your `Kernel.php` file, you have this:

```
protected $commands = [
    App\Console\Command\Test123::class,
];
```

Since you didn't start the class name with a backslash (`\`), it will look for the specified class relative to the current namespace, which for `Kernel.php` is `App\Console`. That is why your error states it can't find the class `App\Console\App\Console\Command\Test123`.

So, if you change that to:

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Command\Test123::class,
];
```

It will now attempt to look for `\App\Console\Command\Test123` from the root namespace.

That leads to the second issue. In your `Test123` class, you have the namespace specified as `App\Console\Commands`, not `App\Console\Command` (you have an extra `s`).

If your file is in the `app\Console\Commands` directory, then your namespace is correct, and you need to correct the `Kernel.php` file to look for the correct class. If your file is in the `app\Console\Command` directory, then your namespace is incorrect, and you need to fix the namespace declaration in your `Test123` class.

Comment: currently, my file Test123.php is in app/Console/Commands folder and this is my current code in kernel.php    protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Command\Test123::class,
]; Now what needs to be changed?

Comment: I did fix the namespace and removed extra s and I get this error: [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  Not enough arguments (missing: "name").

Comment: if I execute php artisan abcd then it does work and execute the code but php artisan make:list does not seem to work yet. I get above comment error

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia Since your directory is `app\Console\Commands`, then your namespace needs to be `App\Console\Commands`. Make sure your Test123 class has this namespace defined, and make sure your Kernel.php file is referencing this class with the correct full class name (`\App\Console\Commands\Test123`)

Comment: I have set everything as you said. I get php artisan abcd running perfectly fine but php artisan make:list does not seem to work probably some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting
>
> Class App\Console\App\Console\Command\Test123 does not exist
>
> How to fix above issue?

In 99,9% it's because you forgot to do

```
composer dumpautoload
```

once you created `Test123` class. Do it now and it should be fine.

**EDIT**

The error message you are seeing shows the full name space to your class which smells to me as I am pretty much certain it should be `App\Console\Command\Test123` instead. If so, edit your `$commands` array to make it look like this:

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Command\Test123::class,
];
```

Comment: I did composer dumpautoload as u mentioned but it does not seem to work. same error

Comment: this is quite weird. I did the change as above but then I am unable to run php artisan or php artisan dump-autoload or php artisan dumpautoload. I did composer dump-autoload which worked. But I guess I am quite stuck. I cant execute  php artisan serve :/

Comment: Instead  of making a file and running the schedule. I have put all my code in schedule call function. when I run it executes right on spot instead of running once every minute. How can I achieve this? when I execute schedule run. I  want the task to execute after a minute. I am using ->everyMinute();

Comment: If my answer solved your **question**, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). If you got another question (related or not), please post a [new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This is how SO works.

Comment: It did not work, so I thought of adding all the code directly in Schedule function. but then even that has issue with executing at every minute.